# current url javascript binding into html

Tags: javascript, html

http://pastebin.com/KejQT7XQ

i am trying to bind current url of my page to this html 
how can i do that

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try to create your iframe dynamically:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   function insertFbButton() {
    f = document.createElement("IFRAME");
    f.setAttribute(
     "src",
     "http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?"
     + window.location.href
     + "&amp;layout=button_count&amp;show_faces=true&amp;width=450"
     + "&amp;action=like&amp;font=arial&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;height=21"
    );
    f.style.width = 450+"px";
    f.style.height = 210+"px";
    document.body.appendChild(f);
   }
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <p>Content</p>
  <script>insertFbButton();</script>
  <p>Content</p>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `window.location.href` or `window.location.pathname` expressions if you don't need the full url